# Variance of $n$ observations

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, discrete-mathematics

What is **variance of** $n$ **observations in simple terms?**

I have been looking articles on google but they are quite hard for me to understand and they are mostly focusing on population (I don't know why). And if possible please give me the formula also.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The two formulae you will commonly see are $\frac1n \sum\limits_i (x_i-\bar x)^2$ and $\frac1{n-1} \sum\limits_i (x_i-\bar x)^2$, where $\bar x=\frac1n \sum\limits_i x_i$ is the mean of the observations.  You may see the first described as the population variance, in effect the variance $\mathbb E[(X-\mu)^2]$ where $X$ can take each of the $x_i$ with probability $\frac1n$.  You may see the second described as the sample variance and is an unbiased estimator of  $\mathbb E[(X-\mu)^2]$ using an i.i.d. sample of $X$ with $\bar x$ being used to estimate $\mu$.

Comment: There are different sample variance estimators, as @Henry pointed out, one being the sample equivalent of the population variance ($\frac{1}{n} \sum_i (x_i - \bar x)^2$), which is consistent but not unbiased, and the unbiased estimator, i.e., $\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_i (x_i - \bar x)^2$. So it depends on what you want in your context.